# Pandas Unmelt dataset

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataset like this

```
    CookieID      ItemID
0   ERG-278-REDD    5651
1   NaN             2377
2   STQ-134-DDVH    1217
3   NaN             1798
4   XYZ-541-EFFG    1234
5   NaN             2378
```

I want to convert it to this in Pandas

```
CookieID          Item1 Item2
ERG-278-RREDD     5651  2377
STQ-134-DDVH      1217  1798
XYZ-541-EFFG      1234  2378
```

I tried using pivot table, but, it didn't work. Here is my pivot table command

```
dfunmelt = pd.pivot_table(dfmelt, index=['CookieID'],columns='ItemID',aggfunc=len)
```

How can I achieve the above output?

Answer (score 2):

- `set_index` + `ffill`
- `groupby` + `cumcount`
- reassign `index`
- `unstack` + `rename`

---

```
s = df.set_index(df.CookieID.ffill()).ItemID
c = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
s.index = [s.index, c]
s.unstack().rename(columns='Item_{}'.format)

              Item_1  Item_2
CookieID                    
ERG-278-REDD    5651    2377
STQ-134-DDVH    1217    1798
XYZ-541-EFFG    1234    2378
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single-liner using `pivot_table`

```
In [371]: (df.assign(no = df['CookieID']isnull().astype(int))
             .ffill()
             .pivot_table(index='CookieID', values='ItemID', columns='no', aggfunc='sum')
             .rename(columns='Item_{}'.format))
Out[371]:
no            Item_0  Item_1
CookieID
ERG-278-REDD    5651    2377
STQ-134-DDVH    1217    1798
XYZ-541-EFFG    1234    2378
```

**Details**

`assign` creates a new column for `NaN` values.

```
In [372]: df.assign(no = df.CookieID.isnull().astype(int))
Out[372]:
       CookieID  ItemID  no
0  ERG-278-REDD    5651   0
1           NaN    2377   1
2  STQ-134-DDVH    1217   0
3           NaN    1798   1
4  XYZ-541-EFFG    1234   0
5           NaN    2378   1
```

Then use `ffill` to fill the `NaN` values

```
In [373]: df.assign(no = df.CookieID.isnull().astype(int)).ffill()
Out[373]:
       CookieID  ItemID  no
0  ERG-278-REDD    5651   0
1  ERG-278-REDD    2377   1
2  STQ-134-DDVH    1217   0
3  STQ-134-DDVH    1798   1
4  XYZ-541-EFFG    1234   0
5  XYZ-541-EFFG    2378   1
```

Then, you could use `pivot_table` as is

```
In [374]: df.assign(no = df.CookieID.isnull().astype(int)).ffill().pivot_table(ind
     ...: ex='CookieID', values='ItemID', columns='no', aggfunc='sum')
Out[374]:
no               0     1
CookieID
ERG-278-REDD  5651  2377
STQ-134-DDVH  1217  1798
XYZ-541-EFFG  1234  2378
```

Use `rename()` to get your column names.

Comment: Will this work if I have more than 2 items per cookie?